# Multiple Conditional Formats: How to add a "Contain" and a "3 Colour Scale" in the same cell?

Tags: excel, excel-formula, formatting, conditional-formatting

So first of all, I like to start by saying I am very inexperienced and so I apologise if there is an easy way to do this.
[The Table I will use. Cost Prices and Pack Names have been changed](https://i.stack.imgur.com/TLqAE.png)

In the dark grey cells, there is a "y". If Mailer A contains Catalogue 1, then F6 is coloured with Conditional Formatting:

"Cell Value begins with 'y': dark grey fill, dark grey font colour"

In G6, the formula =IF(F6 = "y", $E6*F$3, "") is used. F$3 refers to the 100,000, since Mail "A" was sent to 100,000 people.

I wanted to make it so the cells with "y" in them would change how light or dark they are depending on how many mailings were sent to pinpoint what contents are being used the most; in contention with each type of mailing.

All I have tried at the moment is to add different Conditional Formats, but I honestly don't know where to start. I was thinking of using the AND function but, as a novice, I wouldn't know how to implement that with Conditional Formatting :(

Any help is appreciated :)

Comment: Have you tried the 'Colour Scale' option under the Conditional Formatting dropdown? This would shade cells containing numbers, rather than "y", but could be a quick solution.

Comment: @gingerox Unfortunately this isn't what I want as that means having to change each cell almost individually. I'm looking for a quick fix that says: This cell is used AND this cell has 100,000, make it light grey. This cell is used AND this cell is 140,000, make it darker grey, if that makes sense :)

Comment: Sorry for misunderstanding intially - if you select all cells from F6 down to a bottom right corner (M20 in the picture), then go Conditional Formatting -> New Rule -> Use a formula -> =AND(F6="y", COLUMN(F6)=6) . This will shade cells for the 100,000 column, can then duplicate, and replace the final 6 (Column F is the 6th) with 8 (H = 8th) for 110,000, etc.

Comment: @gingerox thank you for the updated response. I assume this means I have to "colour scale" each column individually? Thank you at least, I have valued the mailing numbers in rank of how many there are so it should make things easier in that sense. I would still  prefer an automated way if that's possible :)